# Подовження ДЖ та ДЗ

Tags: фонетика, морфологія

Наскільки [відомо](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B3%D1%96_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%96), наразі подовжуються наступні приголосні звуки **[н], [л], [д], [з], [т], [ц], [с], [ж], [ч], [ш]**:

```
/nʲ/    знання  [znɑˈɲːɑ]
/dʲ/    суддя   [suˈɟːɑ]
/tʲ/    життя   [ʒɪ̞ˈcːɑ]
/lʲ/    зілля   [ˈzʲiʎːɑ]
/t͡sʲ/   міццю   [ˈmit͡sʲːu]
/zʲ/    мотуззя [moˈtuzʲːɑ]
/sʲ/    колосся [kɔˈlɔsʲːɑ]
/t͡ʃ/    обличчя [ɔˈblɪt͡ʃʲːɑ]
/ʒ/     збіжжя  [ˈzbiʒʲːɑ]
/ʃ/     затишшя [zɑˈtɪʃʲːɑ]
```

Однак за лоґікою — через існуючих парних *тш = ч, тс = ц* — і за [довідником з української мови (2001)](http://javot.net/mova/orf.htm#a27) без прикладу, подібна річ повинна бути з **[дз]** та **[дж]**.

Чи є чи було таке в українській мові?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Спроби отримати подовжене ⟨д͡ж:⟩

#### Спроби утворити похідні слова з подовженим ⟨д͡ж:⟩ від слів з основою на *-ґ-*

Теоретично в українській мові мало б відбуватися чергування ⟨ґ⟩ → ⟨д͡з⟩ → ⟨д͡ж⟩: *дзиґа* → *дзидзі* → *дзиджка* (і в деяких діалектах воно таки відбувається).

Відповідно, якщо від таких слів (з основною на *-ґ-*) утворювати іменники в стилі *-??я* (на зразок *безладдя*, *підляшшя*, *роздоріжжя*), то теоретично там мало б бути *-джджя*: *бездзиджджя*, *піддзиджджя*, *роздзиджджя*.

Але окрім того, що не від кожного слова з основною на *-ґ-* є сенс утворювати іменники на *-??я* — навіть у загальновживаних словах літературною нормою вважається спрощений варіант (*дзизі*/*дзижка* замість *дзидзі*/*дзиджка*), тому на практиці у більшості діалектів ймовірно матимемо щось типу *бездзижжя*, *піддзижжя*, *роздзижжя*.

#### Спроби утворити похідні слова з подовженим ⟨д͡ж:⟩ від слів з основою на *-дж-*

В українській мові є декілька слів з основою на *-дж-* іншомовного походження: *імідж*, *коледж*, *котедж*. Важко сказати, як би писалися/вимовлялися утворені від них іменники в стилі *-??я* (на зразок *безладдя*, *підляшшя*, *роздоріжжя*), бо я не бачив, щоб хтось використовував такі іменники (а-ля *безіміджджя*/*підколеджджя*/*розкотеджджя*). Власне, я не маю навіть певності, що *-дж-* у таких словах іншомовного походження справді читається єдиним звуком *⟨д͡ж⟩*.

## Спроби отримати подовжене ⟨д͡з⟩

В українській мові є кілька власних назв жіночого роду з основою на *-дзь*, зокрема польське місто *Лодзь*.

Теоретично в орудному відмідку таких слів ми могли б отримати подвоєне *-дз-* аналогічно до *сіль* — *сіллю*, *міць* — *міцць*, *поміч* — *поміччю*.

Але на практиці і за словниками ([«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/)), і за вжитком в літературі ([результати пошуку орудного відмінку від *Лодзь* у ГРАК-3](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/first?corpname=grac3&queryselector=cqlrow&cql=[lemma=%22%D0%9B%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B7%D1%8C*%22+%26+tag=%22.*oru.*%22+])) маємо *Лодзю*, а не *Лодздзю*.